# Should we handle business decision questions?

Tags: discussion

This question [How can I cover costs without enraging the community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-can-i-cover-costs-without-enraging-the-community) doesn't seem to me to be about site moderation.  This seems to be more of a business model question.  Is this on-topic here?

Note, I did try to check the [What types of questions can I ask here?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section in the help, but it's pretty sparse for the time being, and doesn't really give much guidance.

I don't have a bias either way, I'm just asking to clarify the intent of the moderators.se site.  It seemed off-topic to me, but it ***does*** fall within the scope of [building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-core-mission-of-moderators-stackexchange-com?cb=1), so I'm asking for discussion/consensus.

Comment: I think we'd need to have a few questions of this type and see how well they mesh with our goals before we could officially say they're on- or off-topic. With little thought, it's hard to imagine how "business decision" questions could really involve the community, which is the focus. The specific question, though, is about how to *introduce that decision* to the community without them becoming enraged.

Comment: Note, after having the sample question explained, it's not really a "business decision" question, but I'm leaving the post just so that it's covered in the "what's in scope" discussion during the formative stages of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is pretty borderline.  I do think that the argument can be made that moderation involves holding a community together and getting finances for a community is part of that.  If it was more asking about how to best monetize a community, I think it would move in to off topic, but if it is asking how to cover the cost of the community, I can see the argument that that is a moderation issue.  Without dealing with financing the community, the community would cease to exist.

Answer (score 8):

As the asker of the question, I suppose I should speak up.

I feel this particular question was not about making a business decision, but about how to get the community to support the need to cover costs of community infrastructure. I'm not asking if I should add ads to the site or add a donation button. Instead, I am asking how to approach the community and explain that this isn't cheap.

Money does strange things to people and introducing the need for money in a community that is not used to needing money is going to cause community discussions. I think this is very much a part of "cultivating digital communities." It's a problem that many communities face and approaching it correctly can make or break the entire proposal.

Comment: That makes sense!  With that distinction more clear, I think your question is definitely in scope.  I'm accepting AJ Henderson's answer instead of yours only because he clearly says "If its X it's off-topic, but if it's Y it's on-topic."  I think it better answers the question on where the line is on "business decision questions", but again, the example question IMO is clearly on-topic, and now that you've explained, I see it's not a "business decision" question in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two parts to this.

The first is the business decision on whether monetisation is necessary. This may or may not be a moderation issue, depending on whether moderators on a community are also responsible for its finances (not always the case).

The second, if the decision is that it is required, is the way that monetisation is implemented. I think this is a moderation issue.

Through effective moderation and management, such as informing members of the reasons, effects and scope of the change, you can avoid a lot of issues that result from typically difficult or controversial changes.

Answer (score 2):

One of bigger points of the Area51 site definition was **Community Building**, and at one point it was even suggested that should be the name of the site.

I believe questions about **creating a community from scratch, or expanding the community-related features of a site** (including monetization) should be **on-topic**.